# ctypes: Return object from python function safely without changing pointer address

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a `ctypes` structure and python function:

```
import ctypes

class G(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("data",ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte)),
        ("length", ctypes.c_int)]

        def __init__(self,length):
            self.data = ctypes.cast(ctypes.create_string_buffer(length),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte))
            self.length = length

def func(filename):
    g=G(500)
    buffer=(ctypes.c_ubyte*(g.length))()
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        f.readinto(buffer)
    g.data=ctypes.cast(buffer, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte))
    return g

h=func('filename.txt')
```

The addresses of the object `g` returned by func and that of `h` are different.

Why, and what is a safe way to return the object and its original (correct?) address?

Should I be passing the pointer, or its address, only?

Or is a subsequent dereferencing creating a second pointer to the same object?

Or should I use a global? Or ditch `func` altogether?

Thanks!

Comment: *Python* 2 or 3?

Comment: Python 3 right now, but would be good to hear both

Comment: How is the address different?  `h` and `g` are the same object.

Comment: Could you also post your test code? Also, what is the end goal here? Maybe the approach is wrong altogether.